# How to review a long-winded, overly chatty question

Tags: discussion

In the review queue, I was faced with [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168868/2-words-that-describes-a-keeping-an-argument-on-track) I skipped it, but would like to know how others would deal with it.

It seems very chatty and it takes a long time to get to the point.

Should I take it upon myself to edit such a post, weeding out the chatty part?

Comment: It's kind of wordy and discursive but I think any editing would be too radical. Really, what could you edit out and maintain meaning?